# Missing end of data in created text file

Tags: c#

I am trying to save data from public Web API to a txt file. However,  it seems that somwhere here

```
 using (var fs = FileService.CreateFile("filename.txt"))     
         {    
             // Add some text to file    
             var title = new UTF8Encoding(true).GetBytes(strContent);  
       
             fs.WriteAsync(title, 0, strContent.Length);
         }
```

I am making a mistakes as I am missing some data at the end.

```
public void GetData()
        {
         var path = "https://www.cnb.cz/cs/financni-trhy/devizovy-trh/kurzy-devizoveho-trhu/kurzy-devizoveho-trhu/denni_kurz.txt";
         string strContent;
         var webRequest = WebRequest.Create(path);

         using (var response = webRequest.GetResponse())
         using(var content = response.GetResponseStream())
         using(var reader = new StreamReader(content))
         {
             strContent = reader.ReadToEnd();
             
         }
         using (var fs = FileService.CreateFile("filename.txt"))     
         {    
             // Add some text to file    
             var title = new UTF8Encoding(true).GetBytes(strContent);  
       
             fs.WriteAsync(title, 0, strContent.Length);
         }
         
         var file = File.ReadAllLines(FileService.ReturnBinLocation("filename.txt"));
        
         var results = new List<string>();
         for (var a = 0; a < file.Length; a++)
         {
             results.Add(file[a]);
             File.WriteAllLines(data, results);
         }
         
         var sub2 = File.ReadAllText(data);
        
         sub2 =  sub2.Replace('\n', '|').TrimEnd('|');
         var  split = sub2.Split('|');
         var list = new List<DailyCourse>();
         var i= 0;
         do 
         {
             var model = new DailyCourse();
        
             model.Country = split[i]; i++;
             model.Currency = split[i]; i++;
             model.Amount =  split[i]; i++;
             model.Code = split[i]; i++;
             model.Course =  split[i]; i++;
            
             list.Add(model);
        
         } while ( i < split.Length);
         
       
         var json = JsonSerializer.Serialize(list);
         
        }

 public static class FileService
    {
        public static FileStream CreateFile(string fileName)
        {
           var wholePath =  ReturnBinLocation(fileName);
           
           if (File.Exists(wholePath))    
           {    
               File.Delete(wholePath);    
           }
      
           return File.Create(wholePath);
        }

        public static string ReturnBinLocation( string fileName)
        { 
            var binPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().CodeBase );
            var wholePath =  Path.Combine(binPath, fileName);
            int endIndex = wholePath. Length - 5;
            var sub = wholePath.Substring(5, endIndex);
            return sub;
        }
    }
```

Comment: When you chose to use the async API you must await the async operation: `await fs.WriteAsync(title, 0, strContent.Length);` Otherwise you will leave the using block prematurely.

Comment: Ok, thank you, but the problem is still there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have actually found out that it was this "Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes"when I switched it to Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes. It worked